# dns not resolving

Tags: dns, resolvconf

I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 and DNS no longer resolves. I've got a static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` with `dns-nameservers` and `dns-search` lines.

My `resolv.conf` file appears to be the correct symlink (I ran `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` just to make sure):

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Oct  7 13:03 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

However, running `sudo resolvconf -u` doesn't update the contents:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

It doesn't touch the `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file. My `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file contains the two `nameservers` configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

There are no errors or log messages that I can find. I also tried reinstalling `resolvconf` and rebooting, but no change in behavior.

Running `dig` against the configured `nameservers` works fine.

Comment: If I change resolv.conf manually and rerun 'resolvconf -u' it will revert it back to the above. Adding 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver in /etc/network/interfaces and restarting networking does not update the base file. Manually updating the base file does not trigger any changes either.

Comment: Did you try `resolvconf -a` and than restart networking or reboot?

Answer (score 1):

If you install *pdns-recursor*, it hijacks your `resolv.conf` file. I uninstalled it and reran

```
resolvconf -u
```

and everything started working again.